# Cannot set property 'menu' of null

Tags: angularjs

already i create a sample application in angular.js
At this moment, it's works nice but in console i get a not clear for me error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'menu' of null
at http://localhost/crm/js/controllers/controllers.js:42:29
at F (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:100:187)
at F (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:100:187)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:101:350
at k.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:112:68)
at k.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:109:168)
at k.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:112:398)
at h (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:72:454)
at u (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:77:463)
at XMLHttpRequest.z.onreadystatechange    (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:79:24)
```

I debug my application and i know where it's a problem, but can't resolve it
'menu' is a varaible in my $scope:

```
//editCTRL
app.controller("EditCTRL", function($scope, $routeParams, $http){
var _this = this;

$http.get('api/menu.php?v=edit').then(function(data) {        
    $scope.$parent.menu = data.data;

},function(error){});
});
```

And second ctrl

```
//allCTRL
app.controller("AllCTRL", function($scope, $routeParams, $http){
var _this = this;

$http.get('api/menu.php?v=all').then(function(data) {        
    $scope.$parent.menu = data.data;

},function(error){});
});
```

And now, when i click a some link in my menu (menu items are dynamics get from api, like show in ctrl), and ng-route change a view with ctrl (for example allCTRL to editCTRL) everything its ok, but when we emulate a download some big data (add sleep(1) before echo in api) and we click twice (or more) on link (2+ pendings request in firebug) first of it (after get a data from api) thrown a this error, but last ow request fill model correctly.

Application work fine, but this error just scary me and i didn't know how fix it.
Any ideas?

---

MainCTRL

```
//mainCTRL
app.controller("MainCTRL", function($scope, flowHandler){
var _this = this;
$scope.pageTitle = "MainCTRL";
$scope.menu = [];   

});
```

and view:

```
<html ng-app="CRM" ng-controller="MainCTRL">
<head lang="pl">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>{{ pageTitle }}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 main-menu" ng-include src="'js/views/menu.html'">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 fade-container" >
        <div class="fade" ng-view></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never rely on $scope.$parent to be what you expect it to be. You should probably be using a service for something like this, but rather than explain all of that, my recommendation is to use $rootScope to manage your menu.

In mainCTRL, change `$scope.menu = [];` to `$scope.$root.menu = [];`

In the other controllers where you're doing `$scope.$parent.menu = data.data;`, change that to `$scope.$root.menu = data.data;`

Comment: yeah ofc. in end point i make it with a standalone service, i try change to rootScope and back with information

Comment: Error its still there, after change to rootScope

Comment: But did you initialize the menu like @theJoeBiz said?  If so you may get some error, but it shouldn't be the null error you were getting.  If you are then I would have to say that $scope is null because you would likely be now getting the error on the line where you attempt to initialize the menu but if $scope is null this will still cause an error.  I would say wherever you think your scope variable is being set its not.

Comment: Yes, i initialize menu like @theJoeBiz say... ! nice but when i inject a $rootScope and set menu to root scope like this `$rootScope.menu = []` not like `$scope.$root.menu = []` it's works ! thank you;)

Answer (score 0):

by the error it sounds to be like either $scope and/or $parent are null.  When you try to set a property of a variable that is null you get this type of error.  I would check what the values of $scope and $parent this should lead you to the cause of the error.

Comment: Edit, add view and mainCTRL, where initialize menu

Comment: I'm not sure what that comment means